# javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument: how do I find a html image map in a document?

Tags: java, swing, htmldocumentclass

I'm trying to find a html map in a `HTMLDocument`:

```html
<html>
<map name="imagemap"></map>
</html>
```

With `hdoc` my `HTMLDocument`, I tried the following to get the map but it keeps returning `null`:

```java
hdoc.getElement(hdoc.getDefaultRootElement(), HTML.Attribute.NAME, "imagemap")
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I get the map?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A smart HTML interpreter would entirely remove empty elements.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think a SSCE would help. Either I am calling the method correctly, or I am not.

Comment: Best of luck with it, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the `<map>` nodes with `getElement`. They all get deleted by the HTML interpreter, even those in use.

Instead, use

```java
((Hashtable) hdoc.getDocumentProperties().get("__MAP__")).get("#imagemap");
```

Unfortunately, the `Map` you get from this is a package-private class, so you can't use the data unless you do some reflection.